# Display Port to Thunderbolt Display

Tags: displayport, thunderbolt-display

I have a graphics card that has a standard sized display port(DP). If I purchase a male-to-male display port to mini-display port, will I be able to connect my 27" Thunderbolt display to my PC?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - No.

You can go from Thunderbolt to DisplayPort, but not the other way round.

You can connect DisplayPort devices to a Thunderbolt port, but you can't connect a Thunderbolt device to DisplayPort.

Comment: So there is no way to connect a Thunderbolt display to a PC?

Comment: I can't find a single reference to being able to - yet lots that say you can't. Of course, there's one sure way to find out - try it & see.